# Writing data in .xlsx file with specified font in a certain column

Tags: r, excel, fonts

I intend to save my data to a .xlsx file, and set the font of the i th column to 'Courier New'.

```
c = matrix (rnorm (20), nrow= 4)
```

to .xlsx  format file, and set 'Courier New' as the font of the second column.

```
write.xlsx (c, '1.xlsx')
```

But how to set the font from my R script?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't forget to include the package that you are using in your post (not as a comment). There are a number of packages with a `write.xlsx` function.

Comment: I'm not sure if R packages handle this, but if they don't, you could from R run a shell script actionning vba code that you'd store in some other xlsm workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the openxlsx package to do this.

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()

df <- data.frame(a = c(1:10), b = c(11:20), c = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"))

addWorksheet(wb, 'new sheet')

writeData(wb, sheet = "new sheet", df)

my_style <- createStyle(fontName = 'Arial')

addStyle(wb, 'new sheet', my_style, rows = 1:nrow(df), cols = 2)

saveWorkbook(wb, file = 'example.xlsx')
```

createStyle also gives you control over many more options. 
Take a look here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf